# Scroll one listview with respect to another listview android

Tags: android, listview, deadlock, race-condition

I have two listivew in my fragment layout. If the user scrolls listview1 then listview2 will also be scrolled. Also on scrolling listview2 listview1 will also be scrolled. I am using [drag-sort-listview](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). I managed to do it using boolean flags and onScrollListener but as scrolling first view changes the second view and the second view changes the first it acts like a deadlock condition which is prevented using boolean flags. I keep on getting warning about requestLayout() improperly called hundreds of time. Below is the important portion of the code:

```
boolean playerFirst = false;
boolean positionFirst = false;
onPlayerScroll = new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!positionFirst) {
                playerFirst = true;
                if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    listPosition.setOnScrollListener(onPositionScroll);
                    playerFirst = false;
                } else {
                    listPosition.setOnScrollListener(onPositionScroll);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!positionFirst) {
                listPosition.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem, 0);
            }

        }
    };
    onPositionScroll = new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!playerFirst) {
                positionFirst = true;
                if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    listPlayer.setOnScrollListener(onPlayerScroll);
                    positionFirst = false;
                } else {
                    listPlayer.setOnScrollListener(onPlayerScroll);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!playerFirst) {
                listPlayer.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem, 0);
            }

        }
    };
    listPosition.setOnScrollListener(onPositionScroll);
    listPlayer.setOnScrollListener(onPlayerScroll);
```

And the warning shown in logcat:

```
05-06 13:28:51.850: W/View(12155): requestLayout() improperly called by com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView{42015618 VFED.VC. ......ID 3,3-397,1041 #7f07010b app:id/listPlayer} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
```

How can scroll two listview mutually without running into these conditions.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have so many setOnScrollListener() calls where you only need the last two. Remove all others. Then in onScroll determine the position and call scrolltoposition() for the other one.

Comment: all the setOnScrollListener() inside onscrollstatechanged listener is for disabling and then renabling the scroll in another listview. Without doing this would cause a deadlock between those views.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that disables a listener. Please elaborate.

Comment: It's bit to late, but have you solved your issue? I am facing same issue? Also scrolling large list seems somewhat jerky/slow